# What's Javascript code that Cloudflare is adding to my page?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I use CloudFlare, i check other website who use CF, but they don't have i  this javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:{profile:false},oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok9v=/"},atok:"**",petok:"**-**-**",zone:"**.com",rocket:"0",apps:{}}];var a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.async=!0;a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok9v=b064e16429/cloudflare.min.js";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
```

Anyone can say me, how to disable this ?

thanks

Comment: If you dont want it you get rid of the script. Just erase it....

Comment: he's not in my file ^^

Comment: It's CloudFlare who inject this code, but i want to disable it ^^

Comment: Any why are you trying to disable it? It's there for a reason

Comment: So why is it not on any site that uses the service?

Comment: i just want to know why i have this code ^^

Comment: Do you have a CF badge on your website?

Comment: nop :/ i don't have CF badge :(

Answer (score 5):

By default CloudFlare has Smart Errors turned on domains. This app causes the javascript to be injected. To disable the application, click on `Apps` for the domain, and then scroll down to Smart Errors and click the toggle to change it to 'Off'.

Comment: can't find it there now.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on certain optional apps and performance issues will inject JavaScript because that's how they work.

Comment: Work :) (but i don't what apps i have turning off xD)